# how to use properly webSockets in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, websocket

I'm trying to implement websockets in Symfony2,

I found this http://socketo.me/ which seems pretty good.

I try it out of Symfony and it works, this was just a simple call using telnet. But I don't know how to integrate this in Symfony.

I think I have to create a service but I don't know realy which kind of service and how to call it from the client

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First you should create a service. If you want to inject your entity manager and other dependencies, do it there.

In src/MyApp/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    chat:
        class: MyApp\MyBundle\Chat
        arguments: 
            - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
```

And in src/MyApp/MyBundle/Chat.php:

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    // onOpen, onMessage, onClose, onError ...
```

Next, make a console command to run the server.

In src/MyApp/MyBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;

class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('chat:server')
            ->setDescription('Start the Chat server');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $chat = $this->getContainer()->get('chat');
        $server = IoServer::factory($chat, 8080);
        $server->run();
    }
}
```

Now you have a Chat class with dependency injections, and you can run the server as a console command. Hope this helps!

Comment: Any ideas on how to run this on an average php hosting service? I don't think it's possible to just open up a port like that, nor having a process running for long periods of time (maybe with a crontab hack?)

Comment: I don't know about not being able to use a port on your hosting service. Sounds like something you need to talk to your provider about! You can look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696344/starting-a-websockets-server-in-php-on-shared-hosting/17705521#17705521 as an example of how to run your server as a daemon using php. But if you are using symfony, I would use the Process component rather than popen and passthru. If you want to ask the question, I can show you the code I would use.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Tested on `Symfony v2.4.2` + `Ratchet v0.3.0` everything installed via composer. To test I filled the callbacks with echos like `echo( "onOpen" . PHP_EOL );` then just opened another terminal and did a `telnet 8080`. On connection I got the `onOpen`, typing and pressing enter gets the `onMessage`. I found impossible to close via `CTRL-D` so I closed the terminal issuing the `telnet` and I got the `onClose` in the SF2 terminal.

Comment: Interesting to note that using doctrine with a ratchet server will most of the time lead to a "MySQL server has gone away" error. Indeed, by default MySQL server will close connection after 8 hours and Doctrine does not auto-reconnect to server, you have to handle it manually (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26791224/738091).