# Gearman, ZF2, Doctrine2, MySQL, SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, gearman

I use ZF2, Doctrine2, MySQL, Gearman.
When working Gearman periodically has an error:

***SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away.***

I tried these steps to fix the problem:

**1)** I investigated MySQL queries.
Queries haven't any problem. It's simple (without subqueries) and fast.
For example, this is EXPLAIN of one of queries when MySQL server has gone away.

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+------+
| select_type | table | type  |     possible_keys     |          key          | key_len |  ref  | rows |
+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+------+
| SIMPLE      | t0    | const | UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 | UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 |     767 | const |    1 |
| SIMPLE      | t13   | const | UNIQ_BA388B79395C3F3  | UNIQ_BA388B79395C3F3  |       5 | const |    1 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+------+
```

**2)** I tried the version from [this post](http://circlical.com/blog/2013/9/12/mysql-server-has-gone-away-atop-doctrine2-and-zend-framework-2) (for reconnect to DB) But it's not help me. And some of my queries was lost.

**3)** I disabled all Gearman jobs and workers except 3 for testing. I cleaned Gearman queues and restart Gearman server and Gearman workers. But it's not help me.

**4)** I enabled these settings for MySQL:
       max_allowed_packet   = 500M

```
   max_connections      = 2000
   max_user_connections = 300
   wait_timeout         = 3600
   net_read_timeout     = 3600
```

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you look at MySQL slow query log if there is any clue? Usually this happens when database is busy, running backup, dump or something similar.

Comment: I cleaned my DB.
DB has only 5 rows for testing 
And I turn off dump. It's not help

Comment: Anyway, have you got MySQL slow query log enabled, is something there?
Or check MySQL documentation, it looks like database issue - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html

Comment: The 'gone away' error means the connection to the DB has timed out. This is quite common when working with long running jobs. To fix it just reconnect to the DB at the start of your job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 connection timeout in daemon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060507/doctrine2-connection-timeout-in-daemon)

Answer (score 2):

Each worker script should connect to the database at the start and disconnect at the end. Don't try and hold open the connection as if MySQL times out, then your script won't notice which is why you then get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution described in my blog post (in Russian, you can translate with Google).

http://seyferseed.ru/php/reshenie-problemy-doctrine-2-i-mysql-server-has-gone-away.html

I'm using this code for solving problem with **MySQL server has gone away**

```
public function disconnect()
{
    $this->getEm()->getConnection()->close();
}

public function connect()
{
    $this->getEm()->getConnection()->connect();
}

/**
 * MySQL Server has gone away
 */
public function reconnect()
{
    $connection = $this->getEm()->getConnection();
    if (!$connection->ping()) {

        Debug::vars("MySQL ping failed");

        $this->disconnect();
        $this->connect();

        $this->checkEMConnection($connection);
    }
}

/**
 * method checks connection and reconnect if needed
 * MySQL Server has gone away
 *
 * @param $connection
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
 */
protected function checkEMConnection($connection)
{
    if (!$this->getEm()->isOpen()) {
        $config = $this->getEm()->getConfiguration();

        $this->em = $this->getEm()->create(
            $connection, $config
        );
    }
}
```